# How to filter for "." in MongoDb regex filter?

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I am trying to run a query against a mongodb database.
The user query is a regular expression in a format similar to perl. I'm translating the user's regex to Mongo filter.

Here is the query code:

```
private List<string> GetDocuments(string by_regex)
{
    string regex = by_regex.Replace("[", @"\[");
    regex = regex.Replace("]", @"\]");
    regex = regex.Replace("*", ".*");
    regex = "^" + regex + "$";

    var filter = string.Format("{{_id:'CRF^{0}'}}", regex);
    MyObject item = collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefault(); 
    ....
}
```

Invoking the above method with the regular expression `*.crc` is throwing an exception at the `Find` statement:

`Invalid escape sequence in JSON string '\.'.`

The filter at runtime is `{_id:'CRF^^.*\\.crc$'}` - so I assume this is something with the `.` char escaping, but for some reason I can't find the right way to escape it for Mongo to not complaint.

Comment: Try scaping `.` as `[.]` to see if that does the trick

Comment: @Julio: Thanks - this did the trick...

Comment: Great! I'm adding it as an answer

Comment: I think this is a case of the .NET driver for Mongo not accepting it, because when I use a MongoDB client (in my case, Robo 3T), it accepts `\.` just fine as a part of a `$regex:` value.
Or maybe Robo is smarter than the average bear and is translating it on the fly?  *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, MongoDB seems to try to decode JSON string like `\.`, and that is not a valid scape sequence.

See: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

So perhaps you shoud change `.` to `\\\\.` so that will be encoded as a real `\\` that will be decoded in JSON as `\`

Alternativelly, as I said in my comment, sometimes It is way much easier to use classes for scaping characters. So you may use the `[.]`. That way you avoid the use of backslashes, which are special characters too and they may need to be scaped several times depending of whether the regular expression is a string or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape dot in your regexp like this:

```
db.Test.find({filename: { $regex: '.*\\.crc', $options: 'i'}})
```